# QGIS Layers Not Lining Up

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

I am new to QGIS, I have been using ArcGIS for most of my maps.  I have two layers that are not overlapping properly. One is a shp file from a GIS clearinghouse and another from a delimited text source that I created myself.  I am using the same CRS for the delimited text source as the shp file from the clearinghouse, and I checked "enable on the fly CRS transformation" to see if that would solve my problem as well.

Comment: If the datasets do not align, they are **not** in the same coordinate system. If you can give us some coordinates in both systems, we could look further into detail. We have thousands of CRS, and even lat/lon is not automatically the same.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I set both layers to NAD83 / UTM zone 18N, but they are not lining up.  In the same region one layer's coordinates read something like (-73.230,40.333) and the other reads something like (643465,4244724)

Comment: Thanks again Andre.  It is still not working for some reason.  The layer that is in degrees was the one I created from a delimited text source that I created from a geocoding website using a bunch of addresses for the points I wanted to plot.  For some reason it still won't display properly, even after I set the CRS like you suggested.  Thank you for your helpful answers though, I hope I can arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the coordinates you give, the dataset with (-73.230,40.333) is **not** NAD83 UTM 18N (which should be in metres), but rather NAD83 or WGS84 in degrees.

The second one looks more likely to be UTM coordinates in metres.

So what you have to do is set the CRS for the first **layer** with rightclick `-> Set CRS for layer` to `EPSG:4326`, and both layers should overlap.

This is what I get from your coordinates:

[image: NAD and UTM points]